R Markdown doesn't plot leaflet map in Word document
I'm working on a Word document with a leaflet maps. In RStudio the leaflet maps works good, but when I Knit my Word document with Rmarkdown, no map appears in Word. I recently change my computer and reinstall Rstudio, before that the leaflet maps works fine with Word.
The code below is the code in RMarkdown document.
---
author: "Autor"
title:  "Informe"
subtitle: "Programa"
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%d de %B, %Y')`"
output:
  officedown::rdocx_document:
    plots:
      style: Normal
      align: center
      caption:
        style: Image Caption
        pre: 'Figura '
        sep: ': '
    tables:
      style: Table
      layout: autofit
      width: 1.0
      caption:
        style: Table Caption
        pre: 'Tabla '
        sep: ': '
      conditional:
        first_row: true
        first_column: false
        last_row: false
        last_column: false
        no_hband: false
        no_vband: true
  page_size:
    width: 8.3
    height: 11.7
    orient: "portrait"
  page_margins:
    bottom: 1
    top: 1
    right: 1.25
    left: 1.25
    header: 0.5
    footer: 0.5
    gutter: 0.5
bibliography: referencias.bib
csl: apa-6th-edition.csl
always_allow_html: true
editor_options: 
  markdown: 
    wrap: 72
  chunk_output_type: console
---

library(leaflet)
library(officedown)
library(officer)

leaflet::leaflet() %>% addTiles()

I rebooted my PC, and reinstalled leaflet package.

Did you try to set caching to false? See discussion here.
```{r}
#| label: fig-geolocation
#| fig-cap: Geolocation of participants
#| cache: no
#| echo: false
leaflet::leaflet() |> leaflet::addTiles()
```

Also, there is an old trick as well: save map as widget and then import it as image file.
```{r}
#| label: fig-geolocation
#| fig-cap: Geolocation of participants
#| echo: false
map <- leaflet::leaflet() |> 
       leaflet::addTiles()
htmlwidgets::saveWidget(widget = map, 
                        file = "temp.html", 
                        selfcontained = FALSE)
webshot::webshot(url = "temp.html", 
                 file = "map.png", 
                 cliprect = "viewport")  # cliprect = c(200, 5, 400, 300))
```

EDIT:
According to Yihui Xie, "if you include an HTML widget in a non-HTML output format, such as a PDF, knitr will try to embed a screenshot of the widget if you have installed the R package webshot (Chang 2023)...". Also valid for Word (non-HTML output format).

Thank you, Radovan. I used the second option and it worked fine. However, I noticed that when I installed the webshot package, the maps are printed directly in my word, without the need to apply any trick; when I uninstall it, I have the same problem again.
I did not need to activate the package with library(webshot), just install it.

Yes, you are right. According to Yihui Xie, "if you include an HTML widget in a non-HTML output format, such as a PDF, knitr will try to embed a screenshot of the widget if you have installed the R package webshot (Chang 2023)...". Also valid for Word (non-HTML output format).
